# How to set class on v-menu__content of v-combobox

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to make 3 column dropdown combobox

So I want to add

```
{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(33%, auto));
}
```

to v-menu__content which is made by v-combobox
how do I set class of v-menu__content of v-combobox?
[codepen](https://codepen.io/hongsh93/pen/bGeKprW)

Comment: Could you show some more code?

Comment: i add codepen so you can see there

Comment: Why is this not working and what is your specific question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use contentClass in menu-props:

```
:menu-props="{ contentClass: 'three-dropdown' }"
```

and add style:

```
.three-dropdown .v-list {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(33%, auto));
}
```